# How to decode a string encoded with commas and square brackets to array?

Tags: php, arrays, decode, encode

Could anyone please help me decoding this string?

```
[[["¡hola","hello","",""]],[["interjection",
["¡Hola!","¡Caramba!","¡Oiga!","¡Diga!","¡Bueno!","¡Vale!","¡Aló!"],[["¡Hola!",
["Hello!","Hi!","Hey!","Hullo!","Hallo!","Hoy!"],,0.70910621],["¡Caramba!",
["Gee!","Well!","Good gracious!","Well I never!","By jingo!","By gum!"]],["¡Oiga!",
["Listen!","Hello!","Hullo!","Hallo!","I say!","See here!"]],["¡Diga!",
["Hello!","Hullo!","Talk away!"]],["¡Bueno!",["Well!","All 
right!","Hello!","Hallo!","Hullo!"]],
["¡Vale!"["Okay!","OK!","O.K.!","Okey!","Hello!"]],
["¡Aló!",["Hello!","Hullo!","Halliard!"]]],"Hello!",9]],"en",,[["¡hola",
[1],true,false,999,0,2,0]],[["hello",1,[["¡hola",999,true,false],
["Hola",0,true,false],["saludar",0,true,false],["saludo",0,true,false]],
[[0,5]],"hello"]],,[,"Hello!",[10],,true],
[],3]
```

I have tried `json_decode`but no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Because it's not valid json. Where this string is derived from?

Comment: ya right. I have got this response from translate.google.com

Comment: Then use their [API](https://developers.google.com/translate/)

Comment: I am using Google translate API but its not possible to get multiple translations of a word in a request according to their FAQ section..So I thought this method could help me..

Comment: So what should be your result?

Comment: for example am trying to decode it into `array('Hello'=>array('interjection'=>array("¡Hola!","¡Caramba!","¡Oiga!","¡Diga!","¡Bueno!","¡Vale!","¡Aló!") etc...)`

Comment: @AlmaDo Thanks for your help! I've found a solution on my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution on my own to transform the string to valid JSON. Hope this would help someone.

```
$t = '[[["¡hola","hello","",""]],[["interjection",
      ["¡Hola!","¡Caramba!","¡Oiga!","¡Diga!","¡Bueno!","¡Vale!","¡Aló!"],[["¡Hola!",
      ["Hello!","Hi!","Hey!","Hullo!","Hallo!","Hoy!"],,0.70910621],["¡Caramba!",
      ["Gee!","Well!","Good gracious!","Well I never!","By jingo!","By gum!"]],["¡Oiga!",
      ["Listen!","Hello!","Hullo!","Hallo!","I say!","See here!"]],["¡Diga!",
      ["Hello!","Hullo!","Talk away!"]],["¡Bueno!",["Well!","All 
      right!","Hello!","Hallo!","Hullo!"]],
      ["¡Vale!"["Okay!","OK!","O.K.!","Okey!","Hello!"]],
      ["¡Aló!",["Hello!","Hullo!","Halliard!"]]],"Hello!",9]],"en",,[["¡hola",
      [1],true,false,999,0,2,0]],[["hello",1,[["¡hola",999,true,false],
["Hola",0,true,false],["saludar",0,true,false],["saludo",0,true,false]],
[[0,5]],"hello"]],,[,"Hello!",[10],,true],
[],3]';

    $t = str_replace(',,',',"",',$t);
    $t = str_replace('[,','["",',$t);
    $t = str_replace(',]',',""]',$t);
    $arr = json_decode($t);
    print_r($arr);
```